# How do I do realtime programming in Rust?

Tags: real-time, rust

I'm looking at Rust as a replacement for C/C++ in hard realtime programming. There are two possible issues I've identified:

1) How to I avoid invoking Rust's GC? I've seen suggestions that I can do this by simply avoiding managed pointers and non-realtime-safe libraries (such as Rust's standard library) -- is this enough to guarantee my realtime task will never invoke the GC?

2) How do I map my realtime task to an OS thread? I know Rust's standard library implements an N:M concurrency model, but a realtime task must correspond directly with one OS thread. Is there a way to spawn a thread of this type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1) How to I avoid invoking Rust's GC? I've seen suggestions that I can do this by simply avoiding managed pointers and non-realtime-safe libraries (such as Rust's standard library) -- is this enough to guarantee my realtime task will never invoke the GC?

Yes, avoiding `@` will avoid the GC. (Rust currently doesn't actually have the GC implemented, so all code avoids it automatically, for now.)

> 2) How do I map my realtime task to an OS thread? I know Rust's standard library implements an N:M concurrency model, but a realtime task must correspond directly with one OS thread. Is there a way to spawn a thread of this type?

`std::task::spawn_sched(std::task::SingleThreaded, function)` (the peculiar formatting will be fixed when [#10095](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/pull/10095) lands), e.g.

```
use std::task;
fn main() {
    do task::spawn_sched(task::SingleThreaded) {
        println("on my own thread");
    }
}
```

That said, Rust's runtime & standard libraries aren't set up for *hard*-realtime programming (yet), but you can run "runtimeless" using `#[no_std]` ([example](https://github.com/thestinger/rust-core/blob/master/example.rs)) which gives you exactly the same situation as C/C++, modulo language differences and the lack of a standard library (although [Rust's FFI](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/tutorial-ffi.html) means that you can call into libc relatively easily, and the [rust-core](https://github.com/thestinger/rust-core) project is designed to be a minimal stdlib that doesn't even require libc to work).

Comment: My understanding of `#[no_std]` is that it applies to the entire crate. Could I compile my realtime code in a `#[no_std]` crate to a library then link that with the rest of my application, so I can use Rust's runtime and standard library for the non-realtime code?

Comment: It is crate-wide; and yes, that might be possible but I've never tried it.

Comment: Thank you. I went ahead and learned enough Rust to test it, and it works. If I thought it was going to be this easy, I would've tested it myself earlier.